# Orthographic Frustum?

Tags: three.js, orthographic, frustum

When I check if points are within a frustum using a Perspective camera, it works. But when I check using a Orthographic camera, the frustum box appears inaccurate. The planes are set correctly. Is there something else I'm overlooking that requires changing if using Orthographic camera?

Here's how I'm setting the planes..

```
    if((this.mouse.screenx>mouse.screen.x && this.mouse.screeny<mouse.screen.y)||
    (this.mouse.screenx<mouse.screen.x && this.mouse.screeny>mouse.screen.y)){
        topPlane.setFromCoplanarPoints(camera.position, topRight, topLeft  );
        rightPlane.setFromCoplanarPoints(camera.position, bottomRight, topRight  );
        bottomPlane.setFromCoplanarPoints(camera.position, bottomLeft,bottomRight  );
        leftPlane.setFromCoplanarPoints(camera.position, topLeft, bottomLeft  );
    }else{
        topPlane.setFromCoplanarPoints(camera.position, topLeft , topRight );
        rightPlane.setFromCoplanarPoints(camera.position, topRight , bottomRight );
        bottomPlane.setFromCoplanarPoints(camera.position,bottomRight , bottomLeft );
        leftPlane.setFromCoplanarPoints(camera.position, bottomLeft , topLeft );
    }
    nearPlane.setFromNormalAndCoplanarPoint(vector,camera.position);
    vector.set( 0, 0, 1 );
    vector.applyQuaternion( camera.quaternion );
    var vector2 = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, -config.camera.far );
    vector2.applyQuaternion( camera.quaternion );
    vector2.add(camera.position);
    farPlane.setFromNormalAndCoplanarPoint(vector,vector2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured the issue out.
I was creating my planes so that they extend from the camera's position, however, this creates a frustum that is tapered.
In orthographic mode, there is no tapering- everything is straight, so the frustum planes shouldnt extend from the camera.

What I did was get the direction of the camera:

```
    var vector = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, -1 );
    vector.applyQuaternion( camera.quaternion );
```

And then I used this to create each plane- for example:

```
        var top = topRight.clone(), right = bottomRight.clone(), bottom = bottomLeft.clone(), left = topLeft.clone();
        top.add(vector), right.add(vector), bottom.add(vector), left.add(vector);

            topPlane.setFromCoplanarPoints(top, topLeft , topRight );
            rightPlane.setFromCoplanarPoints(right, topRight , bottomRight );
            bottomPlane.setFromCoplanarPoints(bottom,bottomRight , bottomLeft );
            leftPlane.setFromCoplanarPoints(left, bottomLeft , topLeft );
```

I have it so the frustum could be inverted- so be sure to check if planes are facing right way.